# How to add a @nestjs/swagger controller description?

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I cannot get a description on the controller.

Old version without using Nest:
[image]

New version on Nest:
[image]

[image]

Comment: looks like the only way is using `.addTag('auth', 'description')` on `new DocumentBuilder()`

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: Can we add it as a decorator on a controller? Instead of passing it in the documentbulider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DocumentBuilder#addTag` option when setting up Swagger to document the tag:

```js
new DocumentBuilder()
  .addTag('auth', 'Auth endpoints description')
  .build();
```

There is no option available afaik to add a description at the controller level. You can only add one or more tags at the controller level with `@ApiTags`.